# pm2+ not showing versioning when using ecosystem file

Tags: node.js, deployment, pm2

I'm using [PM2+](https://app.pm2.io/) to manage my NodeJS deployments.

Usually, when I deploy an application with `pm2 start src/app.js`, I get details about versioning like in the screenshot below. However, when I deploy using an [ecosystem file](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) I only get `N/A`:

[image: PM2+ Dashboard Screenshot]

PM2 normally extracts this information directly using [vizion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vizion).

But since it didn't work with the ecosystem file, I specified the GitHub repository directly [just like the documentation stated](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#deployment). 
This is my current `pm2-services.json` ecosystem-file:

```json
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "my-node-app",
            "cwd": "./my-node-app-repo-folder",
            "script": "src/app.js",
            "env": { 
                "NODE_ENV": "production"
            },
            "repo": "https://github.com/MyUserName/MyNodeAppRepo.git",
            "ref": "origin/master"
        }
    ]
}
```

For the `ref` field, I also tried putting `refs/remotes/origin/master`, `remotes/origin/master` and `master`. 
Sadly none of them worked (I made sure they are correct using `git show-ref`).

Additional info:

- NodeJS Version: v15.11.0
- NPM Version: 7.6.3
- PM2 Version: 4.5.6 *(latest, by the time of writing this)*

So, how do I get the `Versioning` field to display correctly?

---

<sub>Note: This isn't really an issue but rather a minor inconvenience. I just want to know what I'm doing wrong.</sub>